# Two types of $n$ Balls into $k$ Boxes

Tags: probability, probability-limit-theorems, balls-in-bins

There are $n$ balls to distribute into $n/k$ boxes (each containing $k$ balls).
$x$ red balls and the rest white balls. ( $x < (n-k)/2$)

What is the probability/bound for having at least one box containing $\ge k/2$ red balls?

Comment: So $k$ divides $n$ and each box gets exactly $k$ balls, yes?

Comment: yess exactly that way